# App moves to next activity when rotating the screen

Tags: android

I have a quiz application and now I am trying to make it work on every screen size, so I made layout resource files for normal, normal-land, large, etc. When i open my app and rotate the screen, the design changes according to those layout files, but it changes the question ( I also have a timer, so the time per question is 20 sec ) and it keeps the timer from the last question ticking. It doesn't crash, and if I run it only in landscape mode or only in portrait mode it works fine.
Thank you!

Comment: try to handle the rotation in your Activity... or try to put `android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"` ect in manifest.

Comment: I am new to android development, and this is my first app, so could you be more specific please? where should i put that in my manifest? Thank you!

Comment: like this...

`<activity
            android:name=".package.YourActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenLayout|keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenSize" />`

Comment: Thank you very much! I added android:configChanges="orientation|screenLayout|keyboard"

Comment: Now it works, but it doesn't change the design

Comment: is it working now ??

Comment: Kind of, because the problem of moving to the next question when rotating the device is now solved, but now when I rotate the device, it doesn't change my design to the landscape one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this... Write this code in your activity

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        setContentView(R.layout.landscapeView);

    } else {
        setContentView(R.layout.portraitView);
    }
}
```

And also add this line in your Manifest file

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```